# Can we avoid specify "num_features" in batch norm of PyTorch, just like Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, batch-normalization

Here is batch norm in TF:

```py
model = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.15, axis=-1)(model)
```

And here is batch norm in Torch:

```py
torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True, device=None, dtype=None)
```

You can see, there is one more parameter: `num_features`. It's very annoying.

Suppose I don't want `affine` in torch, the batch norm in TF and Torch should be the same. Is there a way to avoid specify "num_features" in batch norm of PyTorch, just like Tensorflow?

Comment: Pytorch needs the trainable parameters initialized before running forward otherwise the optimizer won't have access to them. Since the size of batch norm's trainable parameters depends on the number of input channels you need to specify it ahead of time.

Comment: AFAIK, that's true when affine=True. But for `affine=False`, the trainable parameter is not related to the "num_features"(number of input channels) any more.

Answer (score 1):

If you really hate specifying this parameter you might want to look at [lazy batch norm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyBatchNorm2d.html).

Otherwise, you can specify `num_features` as whatever you like (`None`?), as long as BOTH `affine` and `track_running_stats` are `False`. If you look at the base class for the batch norm functions (available at [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/85edb5817925913cdf5a291e61b6066ca329281d/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py#L17)):

```
class _NormBase(Module):
    """Common base of _InstanceNorm and _BatchNorm"""

    _version = 2
    __constants__ = ["track_running_stats", "momentum", "eps", "num_features", "affine"]
    num_features: int
    eps: float
    momentum: float
    affine: bool
    track_running_stats: bool
    # WARNING: weight and bias purposely not defined here.
    # See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/39670

    def __init__(
        self,
        num_features: int,
        eps: float = 1e-5,
        momentum: float = 0.1,
        affine: bool = True,
        track_running_stats: bool = True,
        device=None,
        dtype=None
    ) -> None:
        factory_kwargs = {'device': device, 'dtype': dtype}
        super(_NormBase, self).__init__()
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.eps = eps
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.affine = affine
        self.track_running_stats = track_running_stats
        if self.affine:
            self.weight = Parameter(torch.empty(num_features, **factory_kwargs))
            self.bias = Parameter(torch.empty(num_features, **factory_kwargs))
        else:
            self.register_parameter("weight", None)
            self.register_parameter("bias", None)
        if self.track_running_stats:
            self.register_buffer('running_mean', torch.zeros(num_features, **factory_kwargs))
            self.register_buffer('running_var', torch.ones(num_features, **factory_kwargs))
            self.running_mean: Optional[Tensor]
            self.running_var: Optional[Tensor]
            self.register_buffer('num_batches_tracked',
                                 torch.tensor(0, dtype=torch.long,
                                              **{k: v for k, v in factory_kwargs.items() if k != 'dtype'}))
            self.num_batches_tracked: Optional[Tensor]
        else:
            self.register_buffer("running_mean", None)
            self.register_buffer("running_var", None)
            self.register_buffer("num_batches_tracked", None)
        self.reset_parameters()
```

You can see that `num_features` is being used to set the `self.weight` and `self.bias` when `affine` is True, but also the `running_mean` and `running_std` when `track_running_stats` is True.